# Cannot find email body with selenium(python)

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to get a bot(selenium) to send an email using protonmail.

Once the bot finds the compose button to make an email it pastes the Recipients and the subject :

```
Recipients = driver.find_element_by_name('autocomplete')
Recipients.send_keys(email)

subject = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form    [1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/input')
subject.send_keys('Daily Report')
```

The problem comes when I try to find the body of the email to paste the actual message.

This is the code that i've tried using to find a solution :

```
body = driver.find_element_by_class_name('editor-container fill')
body.send_keys('Sample text ')
--FAIL

body = driver.find_element_by_id('composer1576347472730')
body.send_keys('Sample text ')
--FAIL

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]')
--FAIL
```

I've also tried finding the xpath of the element I believe is suppose to be the body but it didn't work either nor did trying to get the xpath of the div or the id.

This is the page element itself:

```
<div class="angular-squire-wrapper fill"> <iframe border="0" marginwidth="0"
marginheight="0" class="squireIframe" id="composer1576347472730" 
frameborder="0"></iframe> </div>


<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" data-enable
grammarly="false"><div><br></div><div><br></div><div 
class="protonmail_signature_block"><div class="protonmail_signature_block-
user protonmail_signature_block-empty"><br></div><div 
class="protonmail_signature_block-proton">Sent with <a target="_blank"
href="https://protonmail.com">ProtonMail</a> Secure Email.<br></div></div></body>
```

This is the error that I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="composer1576347472730"]"}
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML, code trials and complete error stacktrace.

Comment: I just edited the post so its easier to understand, If you could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see that your the body id you used is of a iframe. You need to switch to the iframe id =composer1576347472730 and then do send key on any input element in that frame..

Comment: About switching iframes: https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

I think your xpath will not work. Try to find id or absolute xpath foe the username/password field.
Search for input tag with textbox or textarea... then send the values to the web element...  I think you cant send values to the division tag.. 
Refer following links
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/browser-automation-using-selenium/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/facebook-login-using-python/

Comment: Could you take a look one more time at my post. I edited the post itself so its easier to see what I  did . I still haven't found a solution :/

Answer (score 0):

I done program in java,I run script for gmail,Hope this help you..

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");


WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]"));
Username.sendKeys("username@gmail.com");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']/span/span")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='password']/div/div/div/input"))));

WebElement Password =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='password']/div/div/div/input"));
Password.sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='passwordNext']/span")).click();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':k1']/div/div")).click();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

WebElement Data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\":q6\"]"));

//Using string
String body = "Hi all";
Data.sendKeys(body);

//Using keys
Data.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"v"));
```

For implicit-explicit wait use this [link](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ill let you know how it goes